# Access 2007 SQL Count

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

i have a table like this

```
Days taken
12
10
10
12
9
10
8
10
```

I want a query that out puts like this

```
Type          | Count
Days over 10  |   2
Days under 10 |   6
```

i have this so far

```
SELECT Sum(IIf([table].[days taken]<=10,1,0)) AS [Days Under Ten], 
Sum(IIf([table].[days taken]>10,1,0)) AS [Days Over Ten]
FROM [table];
```

Which gives me this

```
Days under ten | Days over ten
6              |       2
```

But its not what i want please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query is very close to the correct version. You will want to use:

```
SELECT 
  IIF([days taken] <=10, 'Days under 10', 'Days over 10') as Type,
  count([days taken]) as Total
FROM yourtable
group by IIF([days taken] <=10, 'Days under 10', 'Days over 10')
```

You will see that I used the `IIF` to assign either the `Days over 10` or `Days under 10`. Then you will add that same `IIF` to the  `GROUP BY` to get the `count()`

Comment: @MasterT You are welcome! You were pretty much there in your query, you just needed a little push to the correct result.  Happy to help.